# How does DelegatingFilterProxy know which filter to call to delegate the doFilter call?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters, spring-filter

From Spring's Java docs, web.xml will usually contain a [DelegatingFilterProxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) definition, with the specified filter-name corresponding to a bean name in Spring's root application context.

Does DelegatingFilterProxy use reflection to know the name of its object and use this name to find the name of the filterchainproxy bean and thus delegate the request to the correct filterchain class?

(But then won't two beans with the same name result into conflict?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does DelegtaingFilterProxy use reflection to know the name of it's
>   object and use this name to find the name of the filterchainproxy bean
>   and thus delegate the request to the correct filterchain class ?

Not really. It just query Spring `ApplicationContext` to return a bean which the name is the same as what configured in `<filter-name>` , which finally boils down to calling :

```
Filter filter = applicationContext.getBean(targetBeanName, Filter.class);
```

Behind the scenes , it does not need to use reflection to get a bean by the bean name as internally Spring will index all Singleton beans by its bean name in a map.So looking up a bean by its name is just a key look up from this map.

> But then won't two beans with the same name result into conflict

You are right. That 's why if you define two beans with the same name, Spring will throw exception and it cannot start.

Comment: gr8... that definitely clarifies to good extent. But on the other hand... when we define a servlet or filter class, won't the app container create a class with the  name defined through `servlet-name` or `filter-name`. So is it that the `filterproxychain` class is residing in AppContext space which is not causing a conflict.  And how would the `delegatingfilterproxy` object know it's own name with out using reflection. And after it know's it's name, I see what you quoted is quite the way it is.

Comment: Because `filterProxyChain` is defined in the `web.xml` , the servlet container just parse  it to get its value which do not require reflection.

Comment: In details , in `web.xml` , it will define `<filter> <filter-name> filterProxyChain </filter-name><filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class></filter>` . When the servlet container starts , it will parse web.xml and create `DelegatingFilterProxy` instance  .At the same time , it can get the value  configured in `<filter-name>` which is  `filterProxyChain` from the parsing result. Then it will get a spring bean from the spring context which the name is called `filterProxyChain`.

Comment: ... it's the container you are saying that gets the `filterProxyChain` instance. But the delegation still has to happen through `DelegatingFilterProxy`. So the instance of `DelegatingFilterProxy` still has to know where to delegate the filter calls. Right?

Comment: yes. That 's why `DelegatingFilterProxy` will look up the spring container to  get a bean which the name is called `filterProxyChain` and the type is  `Filter` and delegate the filter call to it .All of them does not require reflection as I already explain in my answer